# Testing custom asset with trustlines that must be allowed - can't send tokens from distribution account

Tags: assets, trustline

I am trying to test the creation of a custom asset - with trustlines that must be authorized by the issuer.  My issuing account (GDQMWZ7XBRY55BU4XQ7FZXFBCUXA2YU2KGPQ7JFZOU3ACXR2ARJAAS36) has auth_required set to true.  I created a distribution account (GCBPMYDHC6YA3CB56F6NRKQTXKZ3AQS3PGXSKM2ZG3AGLJ7C3OUFJSCF), added the trustline to the custom asset (tcFoo), allowed the trust, and then sent tokens to the Distribution account.  So far, so good.

I then created another “end-user” account.  This account, GBTNR6JUFT4MQPTHIJ6ASQADNKFWAD5EB3GCV2SC3SHOE7VPA5ESC4VH, also has a trustline to tcFoo (that has been allowed).   But, I cannot send tokens from the distribution account to this end-user account; I receive an op_no_trust error.  I can send tokens directly from the issuing account to this end-user account, but this isn’t what I need to do (and this would mean other users wouldn't be able to send/receive the token with one another).

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to specify the issuing account when setting up the payment operation - so it was expecting to find a tcFoo Asset from the distribution account.  Everything is now working!